# Why does this event handler have two arrow functions?

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

Can someone help me understand how this event handler is structured? Why do they have two arrow functions lined up?

```
const callAll = (...fns) => (...args) => fns.forEach(fn => fn && fn(...args));
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a higher-order function - a function that returns another function. In this particular case, your function, when given an list of functions, returns a new function that applies these functions in turn to its argument(s). This higher-order function is usually called `compose` or `pipe`, because this is what it does - runs an argument through a series of functions, like unix pipes do (you know, like `grep | sort | uniq`)

Note that your example is not particularly idiomatic, a better way to write it would be

```
pipe = (...fns) => x => fns.reduce((x, f) => f(x), x)
```

which can be used like

```js
pipe = (...fns) => x => fns.reduce((x, f) => f(x), x)


upper = s => s.toUpperCase()
reverse = s  => [...s].reverse().join('')
bang = s => s + '!'

convert = pipe(reverse, upper, bang)

result = convert('hello')

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Translating it to ES5 functions will make it easy to understand. _a "line of code" is worth a thousand words_.

Comment: See Andy's answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's a function that accepts *n* functions, and returns a function that when called with *n* arguments calls each of the supplied functions with those arguments.

Here's the code expanded:

```js
// Accept functions
function callAll(...fns) {

  // Return a function that accepts arguments
  return function (...args) {

    // Which, when called, calls each function with
    // those arguments
    fns.forEach(function (fn) {
      return fn && fn(...args);
    });
  }
};

const addOne = (n) => console.log(n + 1);
const addTwo = (n) => console.log(n + 2);

const addAllTheThings = callAll(addOne, addTwo);
addAllTheThings(3);
```